# How can I pass object type parameter for procedure in PL SQL in delphi?

Tags: delphi, plsql

My stored procedure in PL SQL includes parameter that is from custom object type. How can I pass the parameter in delphi? How to define this in delphi?

Comment: Is this Oracle PL/SQL? If you add a TStoredProc (TOraStoredProc? or whatever component you're using) what parameter type does it give when you retrieve Params?

Comment: You're going to need to [edit] your question and provide more information if you want help here. You've given no information about the parameter that's expected, so it's impossible for us to tell you how to pass it or define it in Delphi or any other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object data types are a very oracle specific concept and you usually don't find support for this on libraries that support multiple databases, like Delphi's dbExpress or even dbGo (ADO).

You don't include information on what data access layer are you using, so I can't specifically address if this particular layer have support for oracle objects or not, and how this works, so this is general advise.

Fortunately you find Oracle Specific data access libraries in Delphi and maybe all of them include some sort of support for oracle Objects. IIRC All the libraries I know of are not free.

For example, using [allroundautomations Direct Oracle Access](http://www.allroundautomations.com/) product, you have the `TOracleObject` class, that you use to read and write *objects* to a oracle database.

For instance, you can invoke your stored procedure with a `TOracleQuery` and pass a object to the procedure calling the `SetComplexVariable` method, passing a `TOracleObject` instance as a parameter.

For more info, take a look at the [DOA manual](http://www.allroundautomations.com/download/doamanual.pdf) (search for `TOracleQuery.SetComplexVariable` method reference).